# Convergence proof of ADAM optimizer

Tags: neural-networks, optimization, gradient-descent, adam

I've read ADAM paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.6980) and found out a suspicious part.

In Lemma 10.3 of Appendix, 
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{\|g_{1:T,i}\|_2^2 - g_{T,i}^2} & \le \|g_{1:T,i}\|_2 - \frac{g_{T,i}^2}{2\|g_{1:T,i}\|_2}\\
& \le \|g_{1:T,i}\|_2 - \frac{g_{T,i}^2}{2\sqrt{TG_\infty^2}}
\end{align*}

They set the bound of 2-norm, $\|g_{1:T,i}\|_2$ of gradient using $G_\infty$, not $G_2$.

Infinity norm is less than or equal to 2-norm, so I think the proof might be wrong.

Can someone tell me what went wrong? Thanks.

Comment: It's less, but reciprocal value for this norms give you opposite sign for comparison. Which means that reciprocals is larger value for inf-norm

Answer (score 2):

The paper is correct, since
$$\|x\|_2 = \sqrt{\sum x_i^2} \le \sqrt{\sum \max_i x_i^2 } = \sqrt{ T \|x\|_\infty^2 },$$
 and for scalars $0 < y_1 \le y_2$, 
$$\frac{-1}{y_1} \le \frac{-1}{y_2}$$

hence
$$- \frac{g_{T,i}^2}{2 \| g_{1:T,i}\|_2} \le - \frac{g_{T,i}^2}{2 \sqrt{T\|g_{1:T,i}\|_\infty^2}} \le - \frac{g_{T,i}^2}{2 \sqrt{T G^2_\infty}} $$

The important distinction is that we are comparing the 2-norm to the square root of $T$ times the infinity norm squared, rather than the 2-norm directly with the infinity norm.

Comment: Could you please change your middle row to use a new variable (e.g. $y \in \mathcal {R}$)? It is confusing when you use $x$ as a vector in the first row, and then as a real number in row 2.

Comment: What is max y if y is a real number?

Comment: Fair point, and given the context I don't need to make a statement about the reals. I've edited the answer so it is hopefully clear now.